# How to make my service stop auto-posting into windows application event log

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, service

I just created a Windows service application in Visual Studio using the Windows Service project template.  When I install and run the service, I notice that it automatically logs certain events to the Windows application event log.  For example:

> Service started successfully.

or

> PowerEvent handled successfully by the service.

I plan to implement my own event logging with more detail, so these auto-generated messages will end up being extra "noise" that I don't want cluttering the log.  Is there any way to prevent the service from writing the default messages into the event log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the autolog property for the service:

```
this.AutoLog = false;
```

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6567h1s.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was easy.